# Word 2016: Print Preview causes Table of Contents to set all page numbers to the same page

Tags: microsoft-word, printing, table-of-contents

Well this is an odd one.

My Word 2016 document has a Table of Contents created using the 'Automatic' style (References > Table of Contents > Automatic Table 1). I can update the table and all is well, however when I do a Print Preview all the page numbers shown in the Table of Contents (ToC) are the same. The Table of Figures (ToF) and Table of Tables (ToT) are also affected in the same way.

More than that, they don't stay the same. If I do nothing more than immediately Print Preview again, they often change to a different number, and then the next time another. My record so far is four changes.

It sounds so bizarre that I had to get a colleague to witness it as I didn't think anyone would believe it otherwise!

If I delete the ToC and insert it again, this seems to fix the problem (and fix the ToF and ToT too, despite not touching them) only until I save it. On re-opening, the problem is back.

I am completely stumped as to what the problem is. Help!

Comment: This sounds like it may be document corruption. Can you provide a link to a sample with the problem in DropBox or OneDrive. You can fill it with filler text if you want. Here is an article I wrote about how to do this. https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_word-mso_win10-mso_365hp/why-a-sample-file-is-important-for-troubleshooting/9441ae3c-1e92-41c6-9a1f-5b377b08e5a5?tm=1619027698258

Comment: Hi Charles, Thanks for the comment. It's not as easy as it sounds because when I remove the contents of the document and replace it with Lorem, it seems to fix the problem. I've been through and deleted areas of the content, then checked if the ToC works, but can't find what in the content might be the problem that way. Any other suggestions?

Comment: Leave any headings as is or replace with lorem text as that heading level.